# jquery dynamic validation rule ignoring message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the JQuery Validation plugin, I have composed the following, but find that the default validation message is displayed rather than my custom message (I have used the constant in other validations, so know that works!). What am i missing?

```
$("#pageform").validate();
$("input[id^=displayName]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.constants.displayNameMaxLength,
        messages: {
            maxLength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.displayName
        }
    });
});
$("input[id^=navigationLabel]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.constants.navigationLabelMaxLength,
        messages: {
            maxLength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.navigationLabel
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: You've misspelled `maxlength`.  Note that it's all lower-case.

Comment: darn case sensitivity gets you every time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
messages: {
            maxLength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.navigationLabel
        }
```

to

```
messages: {
            maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.navigationLabel
        }
```

Note MaxLenth changed to maxlength (L become l)

So complete code should look like

```
$("#pageform").validate();
$("input[id^=displayName]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.constants.displayNameMaxLength,
        messages: {
            maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.displayName
        }
    });
});
$("input[id^=navigationLabel]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.constants.navigationLabelMaxLength,
        messages: {
            maxlength: AGHOSTMOBILEADMIN_VALIDATION.format.navigationLabel
        }
    });
});
```

Here is working code

http://jsfiddle.net/cnrD3/